# Create compound SOAP query condition for AJAX

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, soap, caml

I have a piece of code using Jquery to talk to Sharepoint server and get list data out of sharepoint. The filter is specified with a SOAP enevelope, which is the code below. Currently it has only one query conditon (the code within the query tag), however I would like to have two or more conditions and string them together with AND logic. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
soapEnv =
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
             <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                <listName>Risks Issues</listName> \
                 <query>\
                   <Query>\
                      <Where>\
                         <Eq>\
                           <FieldRef Name='Project'/>\
                           <Value Type='Text'>XYZ</Value>\
                         </Eq>\
                       </Where>\
                   </Query>\
                 </query> \
                <viewFields> \
                    <ViewFields> \
                       <FieldRef Name='Urgency' /> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Item Type' /> \
                   </ViewFields> \
                </viewFields> \
            </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
    </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use [such syntax](http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx#Simple) for your where clause:

```
<Where>\
   <And>\
     <Eq>\
       <FieldRef Name='Project'/>\
       <Value Type='Text'>XYZ</Value>\
     </Eq>\
     <Eq>\
       <FieldRef Name='Project'/>\
       <Value Type='Text'>XYZ</Value>\
     </Eq>\
   </And>\
 </Where>\
```